# Calculus Rates Of Change In A Sphere

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume, area

I have been having problems with this one question for the past few hours. I have been trying to find the radius, but I am not sure that is the way of solving this question. How could I go about this question.

*A spherical balloon is to be filled with water so that its surface area increases at a constant rate of 1cm<sup>2</sup> cm/s.
- Find the volume when the volume is increasing at 10cm<sup>3</sup> cm/s*

Thanks

Comment: What do "1 cm^2 cm/s" and "10 cm^3 cm/s" mean, physically?

Comment: What have you actually tried yourself?

Comment: Choose variables for the key values (time, radius, surface area, volume). Then translate the requirements "its surface area increases at a constant rate of $1\ \mathrm{cm}^2$ and "the volume is increasing at $10\ \mathrm{cm}^3$" into equations. Continue from there.

Comment: The units are incorrect.  The surface area increases at a constant rate of $1~\text{cm}^2/\text{s}$ (area per unit time).  We wish to find the volume when the rate at which the volume is increasing is $10~\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$ (volume per unit time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the balloon starts at 0 cm radius. After *t* seconds the balloon's surface area is *t*, hence the radius is $\sqrt{\frac t{4\pi}}$ and the volume
$$\frac{4\pi}3\left(\frac t{4\pi}\right)^{3/2}$$
We must find where the derivative of this (wrt time) is 10:
$$\frac{4\pi}3\times\frac32\left(\frac t{4\pi}\right)^{1/2}\times\frac1{4\pi}=10$$
$$\frac12\sqrt\frac t{4\pi}=10$$
$$\frac t{4\pi}=400$$
$$t=1600\pi$$
Hence the volume:
$$\frac{4\pi}3\left(\frac{1600\pi}{4\pi}\right)^{3/2}=\frac{32000\pi}{3}.$$
The calculations if the balloon had a non-zero surface area to start are similar, and I leave this as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach:

The surface area of a sphere is $$S = 4\pi r^2$$  Differentiating with respect to time yields 
$$\frac{dS}{dt} = 8\pi r~\frac{dr}{dt} \tag{1}$$
Solving equation 1 for $dr/dt$ yields
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{8\pi r}~\frac{dS}{dt} \tag{2}$$
The volume of a sphere is 
$$V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
Differentiating with respect to time yields
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt} \tag{3}$$
Substituting for $dr/dt$ yields
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \cdot \frac{1}{8\pi r}~\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{r}{2}~\frac{dS}{dt} \tag{4}$$
Solving equation 4 for $r$ yields
$$r = 2~\frac{\frac{dV}{dt}}{\frac{dS}{dt}}$$
Substituting $10~\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$ for $dV/dt$ and $1~\text{cm}^2/\text{s}$ for $dS/dt$ yields
$$r = \frac{2 \cdot 10~\frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{s}}}{1~\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{s}}} = 20~\text{cm}$$
Hence, the volume pf the sphere when the volume is increasing at a rate of $10~\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$ is 
$$V = \frac{4}{3}\pi(20~\text{cm})^3 = \frac{32000\pi}{3}~\text{cm}^3$$